# How to fix Lenovo Thinkpad that won't recognize USB ports

Tags: usb, thinkpad

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T14 running Windows 10.  Recently I noticed a problem reading USB sticks. The first time I put a stick in, it reads it fine.  But if I remove it then later put a stick back in (any stick), it won't read it from either port unless I reboot.  I always eject the stick properly before removing but that doesn't seem to matter.  I checked the device manager and it shows a USB Mass Storage Device with this error:

"Windows cannot load the device driver for this hardware because a previous instance of the device driver is still in memory. (Code 38)

The driver could not be loaded because a previous version of the driver is still in memory."

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Open Device Manager. Look down for USB.  Open (expand it), Right click on each device (not Null Printer unless your printer is USB) and update each driver. Restart and test.

Comment: If that doesn't help, you might try a third-party tool to eject USB devices, such as Safely Hotswap, http://mt-naka.com/hotswap/index_enu.htm (not modified in years, but still more effective on my Win 10 PC, which occasionally fails to eject devices properly).

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I was pointed to this issue from my issue here -> https://superuser.com/questions/1707310/wiindows-10-wont-recognise-usb-stick-after-one-is-removed

Comment: Haven't had a chance to follow up on it yet.  Maybe this weekend.