# Windows 10 - Won't recognise USB stick after one is removed

Tags: windows-10, usb, usb-flash-drive, reboot, usb-storage

I have an issue with Windows 10, *which has only appeared in the last month or so*, where I can put a USB memory stick in and Windows 10 will recognise it and allow me to use it, but once I have "ejected it" from Windows and then removed it from the socket, Windows won't recognise this or any other USB memory stick until after a complete system reboot. So basically the first stick entered after a boot or reboot will be recognised, but none after that will be recognised.

I first thought one of my sticks was maybe corrupt and was causing this, but:

- I have tried multiple different memory sticks
- I have tried reformatting memory sticks
- I have tried FAT32 and NTFS formatted sticks
- I have tried the sticks in both front case USB sockets AND hubs plugged into the back sockets.
- I have looked in Disk manager and the USB memory sticks do not appear in there when they are not being detected. (Obvs they do appear when if they are the "first stick of the day" and do get recognised.)

It is getting a bit of a bind to have to restart the PC every time I need to enter a new USB drive. Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT 1:**

- All USB drivers are "the best drivers are already installed", according to Windows.
- Non-drive USB devices work after the USB drive is removed so it may not be a USB socket issue but more of how windows detects a new drive after ejection.
- Even putting another different USB drive in a different socket will also not trigger the new drive to be recognised.
- In **Device Manager** all USB hubs are set to **NOT ALLOW** computer to turn off power
- As per comment suggestion, visited this issue, and nothing suggested there helper either. [How to fix Lenovo Thinkpad that won't recognize USB ports](https://superuser.com/questions/1706848/how-to-fix-lenovo-thinkpad-that-wont-recognize-usb-ports)

**EDIT 2:**
Oddly after a couple of months of having this issue the issue resolved itself over the last few days. I have to assume a software update of some kind must have fixed it, as I had done nothing proactive in that time frame, and all else I had tried had failed.

Comment: Try to test Windows integrity by running [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Does this also happen with other devices than storage devices?

Comment: You likely have enabled the OS to power off the USB port(s) once a device is ejected from it, and while I don't recall where this setting is, it should be able to be found by using a search engine _(IIRC, open Device Manager, open the tree for USB controllers, right-click on the controller, Properties, then Power Management, albeit I believe there's also a setting somewhere else regarding powering off the USB port once a device is ejected)_

Comment: @JW0914 - I will certainly look that up - thank you. I have certainly not actively turned on that setting though.

Comment: @mashuptwice - I will check that out. I have not tried plugging a non USB Drive into the same socket afterwards.

Comment: @harrymc - That could be a good idea after exhausting all others. Thank you

Comment: Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/1706848/how-to-fix-lenovo-thinkpad-that-wont-recognize-usb-ports

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - unfortunately "the best drivers are already installed"

Comment: @mashuptwice - I have tried a non-drive USB device and that works. It is just drives that will not work

Comment: You may try Zentimo (Trial) https://zentimo.com/  and handle the usb mass storage devices and check again how this tool handles them on windows 10.